# Power Spectral Density of vacuum fluctuations in harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I was thinking about the question whether vacuum fluctuations in the non relativistic quantum harmonic oscillator actually have a power spectral density.
The power spectral density is (to my knowledge) just the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function.
Where the autocorrelation function is just the expected value of the "signal" (in this case position or momentum) multiplied by the time translated signal.
I tried calculating it and I encounter difficulties in the interpretation of the results:
$$E[x(t)x(t+\tau)]=\langle 0 |x(t)x(t+\tau)|0\rangle$$
If one substitutes the formulae of the position operator in terms of the ladder operators one finds that only a single term remains since the other terms annihilate the vacuum on either the left or the right.
So finally what remains is:
$$E[x(t)x(t+\tau)]=e^{i\omega_0 \tau}$$.
How can the autocorrelation function be complex if we used hermitian operators? What does this even mean?
If one takes the Fourier Transform one can "shed some light" on it because the Fourier transform of that is simply $$\mathcal\delta(\omega-\omega_0)$$ So it has a spectrum at exactly the frequency of the harmonic oscillator. But it is only one sided. Is maybe the definition of the autocorrelation flawed here?

Comment: The autocorrelation function here is complex because of operators $x(t)$ and $x(t+\tau)$ do not commute.

Comment: so what is the interpretation of a complex autocorrelation function.

Comment: I don't know the interpretation. I just answered the question "How can the autocorrelation function be complex if we used hermitian operators?".